# Has anything precise been written about the Fukaya category and Lagrangian skeletons?

Tags: fukaya-category, sg.symplectic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

At some point in this past year, some Fukaya people I know got very
excited about the Fukaya categories of symplectic manifolds with "Lagrangian skeletons."  As I understand it, a
Lagrangian skeleton is a union of Lagrangian submanifolds which a
symplectic manifold retracts to.  One good example would be the
zero-section of a cotangent bundle, but there are others; for example,
the exceptional fiber of the crepant resolution of $\mathbb
C^2/\Gamma$ for $\Gamma$ a finite subgroup of $SL(2,\mathbb C)$.  From the rumors I've heard, apparently there's some connection between the geometry of the skeleton and the Fukaya category of the symplectic manifold; this is understood well in the case of a cotangent bundle from work of [Nadler](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0612399) and [Nadler-Zaslow](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0604379)

I'm very interested in the Fukaya categories of some manifolds like
this, but the only thing I've actually seen written on the subject is
Paul Seidel's moderately famous picture of Kontsevich carpet-bombing
his research program

[image: This flaming pile of rubble is my research plans for the next few years]

which may be amusing, but isn't very
mathematically rigorous.  Google searching hasn't turned up much, so I
was wondering if any of you have anything to suggest.

Answer (score 26):

I noticed this question has been bumped up to the front page, and the
most recent answer is about 8 years old: the subject has moved on
since then, and more has been written. Here is my understanding of
some of the recent developments.

Caveat: This whole area has undergone rapid progress in the last few
years, and I am not working on this question, so what I say is
probably not up-to-date (even as I write, never mind in the future).

Kontsevich's idea was that you can relate the Fukaya category of a
Weinstein manifold to the microlocal sheaf category of its
skeleton. As far as I know, a proof of this conjecture is work in
progress by Ganatra-Pardon-Shende ([one preliminary part of which is
already available](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03152)).

I think the idea of their proof is roughly the following:

- You prove that the Fukaya category has a co-sheaf property, which
  means it can be computed locally first on some subsets and then the
  answer can be glued together using homotopy colimits. For this, you
  need suitable functors relating the Fukaya category of a subset to
  the Fukaya category of the whole manifold. This is complicated by
  the fact that your "subsets" might not be very nicely embedded in the
  whole manifold: for example, if your ambient manifold is $T^*M$ then
  you want to allow subsets like $T^*M'$ where $M'\subset M$ is a
  codimension zero submanifold with boundary (that's because you
  ultimately want to work locally on the skeleton). That is
  problematic because the Liouville vector field for $T^*M'$ and the
  Liouville vector field for $TM$ don't match up nicely. The first GPS
  paper constructs these categories and functors for "Liouville
  sectors" (a suitably broad class of inclusions, related to [Sylvan's
  notion of stops and partially wrapped Floer homology](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.02540)). I think the proof of the co-sheaf property is still ongoing work?
- Now you compute the local pieces of the Fukaya category and show
  that they agree with the microlocal sheaf categories; since both
  have co-sheaf gluing, you get the same global answers.

The second part relies on some local computations of Fukaya
categories. [Nadler has introduced the
notion of "arboreal skeleton"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.4122) which is a skeleton with certain
"generic" singularities. For example, trivalent graphs in dimension 1;
trivalent graph times interval or cone on 1-skeleton of a tetrahedron
in dimension 2; etc. He computes the microlocal sheaf category for
these; I'm not sure if the corresponding partially-wrapped Fukaya
categories have been calculated in all cases yet. Finally, you want to
show that any Weinstein manifold has an arboreal skeleton:
[Starkston has some results in this
direction which may represent the state of the art](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.03446).

Leaving this aside for a moment, there are also special cases where
the Konstevich conjecture/local-to-global results for the Fukaya
category has been established independently of this general
program. These include (but again, I'm probably missing some):

- Nadler https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.02977
- Pascaleff-Sibilla https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.06448
- Nadler https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.00114
- Lee https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.04473
- Gammage-Nadler https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.03255
- Shende https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.07663

Answer (score 15):

A comment re. Jonny's nice answer: there was indeed a time when that was the envisioned strategy of proof.  However our present approach does not require the arborealization.  Because: [now we know](https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.08807) that the Fukaya and microlocal categories associated to any (singular) Legendrian in a cosphere bundle agree.

--

In [GPS2](https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.03427), we prove descent for general sectorial covers.  In particular, one could deduce the existence of said cosheaf by an (unwritten) purely geometric argument that an open cover of the skeleton lifts to a sectorial cover of the symplectic manifold.  However, the notion of sectorial cover is more flexible, as it is not tied to a particular skeleton; in a certain sense it captures all skeleta at once.

The real virtue of the cosheaf on the skeleton is that it is not some arbitrary cosheaf of categories, but in fact is the Kashiwara-Schapira stack of microlocal sheaf theory. (Historical note: this assertion goes beyond the original conjecture of Kontsevich, and is probably best attributed to Nadler.) As mentioned above, [GPS3](https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.08807) is the required local
calculation.  In principle, one could use [GPS2](https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.03427) to glue, but actually there is a short-cut for most Weinstein manifolds of interest in mirror symmetry and geometric representation theory.  The reason is that these manifolds typically have trivial stable symplectic normal bundle, so one can use the [embedding trick](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.07663) without messing about with descent from a Lagrangian Grassmannian bundle. This reduces the problem to the cotangent comparison of [GPS3](https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.08807), provided one has certain full faithfulness of embedding results in both partially wrapped Floer theory and in microlocal sheaf theory.

Full faithful embeddings come from a certain doubling construction, which was originally introduced in sheaf theory by Guillermou, it is described in e.g. section 11.4 of his [omnibus](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.07341).  Guillermou assumes there that the relevant skeleton is smooth, but similar ideas give a construction in general and appear in Sec. 6 of [my paper with Nadler](https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.10154).  On the wrapped Floer theory side the construction is Example 8.6 in [GPS2](https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.03427).  Combining the above one learns that for a Weinstein manifold with stably trivial symplectic normal bundle, the wrapped Fukaya category is equivalent to the category of microlocal sheaves on any Lagrangian skeleton.

(Most likely the `embedding trick' also works to establish the result in the general case, but this requires a bit more complicated argument.)

Answer (score 10):

There are a few comments about this in the [notes from Kontsevich's talk](http://www.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/preprints/send?bid=4024) ([Internet Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20100114095135/http://www.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/preprints/send?bid=4024)) at the [Arbeitstagung](http://www.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Events/This+Year+and+Prospect/AT+2009/AT+program/) ([Internet Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20110112112636/http://www.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Events/This+Year+and+Prospect/AT+2009/AT+program/)).

I also attended the Seidel talk that people are referring to. I should have my notes somewhere; if I succeed in finding them and if they contain anything not already in Sheel Ganatra's notes, I'll scan them and post them.

Edit: Kontsevich spoke about [this last week in Miami](https://klein.mit.edu/%7Eauroux/frg/miami10.html). Check out [these notes](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Eauroux/frg/miami10-notes/M.%20Kontsevich%20-%2020-01-10%20-%20Singular%20Lagrangian%20branes.pdf) from the talk. Find the abstract [here](https://klein.mit.edu/%7Eauroux/frg/miami10-abstracts.html).

Comment: Good spot, Kevin!

Comment: If only I could vote you up again...

Comment: Since the two links mentioned in the first paragraph no longer work, I have added version from Internet Archive. It seems the same text is available here - and this link is still working: https://www.ihes.fr/~maxim/TEXTS/Symplectic_AT2009.pdf (just in case, here is link to the [Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20180830123619/https://www.ihes.fr/~maxim/TEXTS/Symplectic_AT2009.pdf)).

Answer (score 5):

On this topic I've only seen Ganatra's notes from Paul's Talbot talk (see Scott's answer). An aspect of this, that a Fukaya category can behave in a sheafy way, is part of Nadler's proof that "microlocal branes are constructible sheaves".

The most relevant reference I can think of for the Fukaya category of the crepant resolution of $\mathbb{C}^2/\Gamma$ is [Abouzaid's paper about Floer theory in plumbings](https://arxiv.org/abs/0904.1474).

Bad form as it may be, I'll ask a reciprocal question in this answer box. Suppose you knew that the Fukaya category of this crepant resolution was the constructible derived category on the exceptional fibre (was that what you had in mind?). What could one deduce? Would there then be a quiver presentation? A reasonable description of Hochschild cohomology?

Answer (score 4):

I asked Paul a couple months ago, and he said that nothing has been written, but there may be notes floating around from some talks Kontsevich gave in France last March.  There are a few examples given in the last talk at Talbot [on the bottom of this page](https://math.mit.edu/events/talbot/index.php?year=2009&sub=talks).  I was unable to work out a precise mathematical statement from the information given, but I'm not a symplectic geometer.

Comment: The link in the post seems to be dead - I mean the part: "the last talk at Talbot [on the bottom of this page](http://math.mit.edu/conferences/talbot/index.php?year=2009&sub=talks)". Is it perhaps supposed to be some of the talks listed here: [Talbot 2009: Fukaya categories](https://math.mit.edu/events/talbot/index.php?year=2009&sub=talks) ([Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20220129062828/https://math.mit.edu/events/talbot/index.php?year=2009&sub=talks)?

Comment: @MartinSleziak Yes, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is helpful to you, but Bing came upon this paper by Ruan which I'm thinking you likely have already seen and "get."

[The Fukaya category of symplectic neighborhood of a non-Hausdorff manifold](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0602119)